# How to install hexo blog in a remote repo to local machine?

Tags: github-pages, hexo

I'm using hexo in github page. Mistakingly I deleted my local file in my local machine. I tried to make a new local file again by using `git clonehttps://github.com/aaayumi/aaayumi.github.io.git`. Then I installed `npm install hexo-cli -g`.

I could install all necessary files but when I typed  `hexo deploy`,
it shows,

```
hexo deploy
Usage: hexo <command>

Commands:
  help     Get help on a command.
  init     Create a new Hexo folder.
  version  Display version information.

Global Options:
  --config  Specify config file instead of using _config.yml
  --cwd     Specify the CWD
  --debug   Display all verbose messages in the terminal
  --draft   Display draft posts
  --safe    Disable all plugins and scripts
  --silent  Hide output on console

For more help, you can use 'hexo help [command]' for the detailed information
or you can check the docs: http://hexo.io/docs/
```

Is there an way to be able to use hexo blog locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in https://github.com/aaayumi/aaayumi.github.io is not the source code of your blog, it is just the generated content. What you need are the original markdown files that were inside your `source` folder.

You will have to recreate the blog with `hexo init` and rewrite your blog posts .. Sorry for that.

Of course you can look at your website directly (http://ayumi-saito.com/) and rewrite the posts, copy pasting from there which should not take that long.

Also to make sure this does not happen again, you can publish your blog source files in a different repository. So that there is always a copy somewhere.

PS: Thanks for using my theme ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for kind explanation! I will try to avoid that a same thing happen again. Thank you so much for making a beautiful theme!! ;D